# NFS server not exporting host present in /etc/exports

Tags: centos, nfs

I have a NFS server running on CentOS 7.2 and I have a problem with one (path/client host) declared in my `/etc/exports` that should be exported and that is not...

My `/etc/exports` file :

```
/mnt/data/ host1(rw,all_squash,anonuid=1001,anongid=1001)
/mnt/data/ host2(rw,all_squash,anonuid=1001,anongid=1001)
/mnt/data/ host3(rw,all_squash,anonuid=1001,anongid=1001)
/mnt/data/ host3(rw,all_squash,anonuid=1001,anongid=1001)
```

I restarted my nfs server and do `exportfs -a` so the output of `cat /var/lib/nfs/etab` is correct:

```
/mnt/data   host1(rw,sync,wdelay,hide,nocrossmnt,secure,root_squash,all_squash,no_subtree_check,secure_locks,acl,no_pnfs,anonuid=1001,anongid=1001,sec=sys,rw,secure,root_squash,all_squash)
/mnt/data   host2(rw,sync,wdelay,hide,nocrossmnt,secure,root_squash,all_squash,no_subtree_check,secure_locks,acl,no_pnfs,anonuid=1001,anongid=1001,sec=sys,rw,secure,root_squash,all_squash)
/mnt/data   host3(rw,sync,wdelay,hide,nocrossmnt,secure,root_squash,all_squash,no_subtree_check,secure_locks,acl,no_pnfs,anonuid=1001,anongid=1001,sec=sys,rw,secure,root_squash,all_squash)
/mnt/data   host4(rw,sync,wdelay,hide,nocrossmnt,secure,root_squash,all_squash,no_subtree_check,secure_locks,acl,no_pnfs,anonuid=1001,anongid=1001,sec=sys,rw,secure,root_squash,all_squash)
```

But when I run `showmount -e` it does not show me host1 :

```
/mnt/data host2 host3 host4
```

And actually I could not mount `/mnt/data` from host1 :

```
[root@host1 ~]# mount -a
mount.nfs: access denied by server while mounting nfs-server:/mnt/data/
```

Whereas the mount is OK from host2,3 and 4.

PS :For information :

- host1...hostn can see and ping the NFS server
- SElinux has been deactivated for tests
- No firewall neither on server nor on client (VM are clones one from each other)

---

**Edit**:

Thanks for your responses.

`strace` does not show much things:

```
stat("/run", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=960, ...}) = 0
stat("/run/mount/utab", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
getcwd("/root", 4095)                   = 6
readlink("/root/nfs-server:", 0x7ffe3a9ee090, 4096) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
readlink("/mnt", 0x7ffe3a9edf70, 4096)  = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
readlink("/mnt/data", 0x7ffe3a9edf70, 4096) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
stat("/sbin/mount.nfs", {st_mode=S_IFREG|S_ISUID|0755, st_size=113400, ...}) = 0
clone(child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7fd1b08f6b50) = 51633
wait4(-1, mount.nfs: access denied by server while mounting nfs-server:/mnt/data/
[{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 32}], 0, NULL) = 51633
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=51633, si_status=32, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
close(1)                                = 0
close(2)                                = 0
exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

What I see about running services on host1 side is that no `nfsv4.0-svc` service is running :

```
[root@host1 ~]# ps -aux --forest | grep nfs
root      1199  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Feb15   0:00  \_ [nfsiod]
```

whereas it is running on other hosts that succeed in mounting `/mnt/data`

```
[root@host2 ~]$ ps -ef | grep nfs
root      1296     2  0 févr.15 ?     00:00:00 [nfsiod]
root      1302     2  0 févr.15 ?     00:00:00 [nfsv4.0-svc]
```

But I don't know if it is a cause or a consequence (i.e. `nfsv4.0-svc` is running because the mount succeed...) : could it be the source of the pb ?

Comment: Can you paste the output of `strace` on `[root@host1 ~]# mount -a` , such as `strace mount -a`

Comment: Can you please make sure all nfs related packages are installed on host1 and all the services are enabled and started

Comment: Disable Selinux on both server and host1

Comment: Can you do a port scan from host1 to server? Can you see the NFS service ports from client , use `nmap` and `telnet`

Comment: NFS clinet versions are the same on all hosts??

Comment: Can you specify the nfs version when mounting? such as `sudo mount -o v3 a-nfs-server:/path/to/export /path/to/mount`  , which nfs version u are using , v3 or v4?

Comment: Does `host1` resolve to the same IP as one of the other hosts? I think that stracing `rpc.mountd` while doing `exportfs -a` would be more helpful...

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the last post that was not a response... I'm quite new to stackexchange.

I finally found the problem: when running `showmount -e` or `showmount -e [nfs-server DNS]`, the showed exports was not good.

But when running `showmount -e localhost` or `showmount -e [nfs-server IP]` its showed the correct exports (with host1 within).

So running my mount on host1 with the nfs-server IP solve the problem (too bad for our clone VM automation based on DNS...)

We are running or infrastructure on Azure so perhaps this DNS issue comes  from it.

Thanks.

Alex.